# Magento 2 FPC invalidate homepage, specific product page and specific category cache in observer

Tags: magento2, event-observer, full-page-cache

I need to create on observer that should invalidate cache of the homepage, a specific product page and a specific category cache when a trigger occurs. Anyone can help ?

Thanks !

Comment: have you found any solution?

Comment: @Knight017 unfortunately no solution yet.